# How to create ground and vcc pins

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

I try to create a GND pin and a VCC pin to connect them to a battery. On my eagle pcb I haven't found them. They should be like 5mm x 5mm.

On the schematic I added a ground and vcc pin, but I can't found them on the pcb.

I need a place (copper) to solder the battery connectors.

Is there a good way to do this easily?

Comment: You really need to have a datasheet for what you are trying to make, if it just a through hole with pads then you can make a 5x5mm hole (or via) or you can make a library component for it  - but like I say, you really need a datasheet as they'll likely have a recommended footprint for it

Comment: Why? I only need a small copper place to solder the battery connector cables there.

Comment: Maybe I can do it with the polygon tool??

Comment: You still need to make a 'package' for it if you want to name just a pad, if you are happy to make it a small via with a diameter of 5mm then you can name these vias the same as the connections you want them to be made to and it'll work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best option would be to use the via tool. Create the drill size to be the minimum of you PCB manufacturer (0.25mm is what I have mine set to) and then make the diameter of the pad to be 5mm.

You can then place these wherever you like on the board (making sure that it doesn't overlap anything) and then rename one to "GND" (or whatever your ground plane is named) and the other to "VCC" (or whatever you batteries postive terminal connections are called on the schematic). Then you can draw the tracks and everything is good.

This would be a sort of quick and lazy way to do it, the proper way would be to create the pad in Eagle's library editor and connect it to the schematic symbol so you can have the back annotation feature of Eagle working with you.

If you're likely to be using this component again in the future then I would advise creating the package as it would remove any possibility for forgetting to place them on the board.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is to define a "part" of the size and shape you want. You can then connect it in the schematic editor, it shows up on the PCB, you can move it around, route to it, add a component designator in the silkscreen, etc.

This is also useful for defining plated holes for mounting bolts.